# How to walk through a python array/object similar to PHP's foreach function

Tags: python, arrays, foreach, eval, repr

I'm new to Python, sorry for asking such a probably simple question.

I'm hacking a script which has an Array(?) which I can print with the following command:

`repr(Interfaces.log_manager.job_log[user_id]))` gives me:

```
{
'3f2': ('3', 0.0078125, 1405595247.855199), 
'3f1': ('3', 0.00390625, 1405595247.855164), 
'3ed': ('2', 0.0078125, 1405595227.65275), 
'3ec': ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852576), 
'3eb': ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852538)
}
```

I know want to sum up the 2nd values in the parentheses and get the min and max value of the third in the parentheses.

In PHP this is possible with a foreach... How is that done in Python ?

My result should/would be:

```
sum = 0.0312496
mintime: 1405595202
maxtime: 1405595247
```

Any help very appreciated

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> a = {'3ec': ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852576), '3ed': ('2', 0.0078125, 1405595227.65275), '3f2': ('3', 0.0078125, 1405595247.855199), '3eb': ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852538), '3f1': ('3', 0.00390625, 1405595247.855164)}
>>> min_val = min([x[2] for x in a.values()])
>>> max_val = max([x[2] for x in a.values()])
>>> sum_val = sum([x[1] for x in a.values()])
>>> print min_val, max_val, sum_val
1405595202.85 1405595247.86 0.02734375
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfect and as expected. never thought it could be so simple :)

Comment: Python makes things simpler ;)

Answer (score 3):

First of all your data structure is `dict` in python, so you should ;

```
for k,v in l.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

The output;

```
3ec ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852576)
3ed ('2', 0.0078125, 1405595227.65275)
3f2 ('3', 0.0078125, 1405595247.855199)
3eb ('2', 0.00390625, 1405595202.852538)
3f1 ('3', 0.00390625, 1405595247.855164)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate PHP's `foreach` with `for` in python, i.e.

```
for key, value in Interfaces.log_manager.job_log[user_id].iteritems():
```

and the data between the braces is just an array, so you can refer to the elements as `value[0]`, `value[1]`, etc, in the aforementioned example.

Answer (score 0):

In python, a mapping (or associative array in PHP) is called a Dictionary (or dict for short). One thing to note, is that the order of iteration over a python dictionary is not guaranteed. In python you can loop over a dictionary in a variety of ways. The most simple is to iterate over the dictionary's keys

```
for k in D:
    #k is the key, D[k] is the value
    print k, D[k]
```

For convenience, you can get both key and value at once, using a dictionaries .iteritems method, which returns a sequence of (key, value) tuples that can be implicitly unpacked into multiple variables by the for loop syntax as in

```
for key, val in D.iteritems():
    print "Key:", key
    print "Value:", value
    print
```

I you are not interested in the keys at all, you can use the .values method of dictionaries, for example

```
for val in D.values():
    print val
```

A complete solution to your problem would be

```
import sys
sum = 0
minv2 = sys.maxint
maxv2 = -sys.maxint
for val in Interfaces.log_manager.job_log[user_id].values():
    sum += val[1]
    if val[2] < minv2:
        minv2 = val[2]
    if val[2] > maxv2:
        maxv2 = val[2]
print "sum =", sum
print "mintime:", minv2
print "maxtime:", maxv2
```